# Objective C - Given a layer, how to check if it finished drawing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layer

I am trying to check if a layer finished drawing, and it is ready to receive taps.

I tried calling various commands on the layer (`needsDisplay`, `needsLayout` etc.) but they all return same value independent of the drawing state.

Comment: What do you mean with "finished drawing"? Do you mean "actually visible on screen"?

Comment: No, I meant "it is ready to receive taps"...

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe in my case I'd be interested to know when it's ready to perform e.g. a property animation `myLayer.endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI)`. Immediately after creation the animation doesn't work, it just shows the end state. It works with a 0.1 delay. Don't see a method to be overriden, delegate or anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Default animations:

   Accessing the presentationLayer property of an object in the layer. While an animation is in progress, you can retrieve this object and use it to get the current values for those animations.

   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer
2. Custom animations:

   Add a completion block to the current transaction using the setCompletionBlock: method. When all of the animations in the transaction finish, the transaction executes your completion block.

   Assign a delegate to your CAAnimation object and implement the animationDidStart: and animationDidStop:finished: delegate methods.

   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1

Answer (score -1):

I think one method you should cast is checking layer frame size. If the size is pozitive, you know this layer is displayed and did finish drawing.

```
    CALayer *newlayer = [[CALayer alloc]init];
    newlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    newlayer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
    newlayer.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:newlayer];
    if(newlayer.frame.size.width > 0 || newlayer.frame.size.height >0) {
    NSLog(@"added to view");
    }
```

If you are drawing an image for example in layer you can log the moment you call   UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); So here you already have your image.

Comment: Please provide rationale for this proposal. How is the frame size connected to drawing state?

Comment: Maybe checking glCheckFramebufferStatus is a better way.